# Category table for 2 different entities with M-2-M. Should i split it? [PostgreSQL]

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I am developing a database for a building company website using Django/PSQL. I have a *shop* app with **Services**, **Products (Goods)** and **Categories** models. Both Products and Services have categories, so i have created a recursive table that will contain categories/subcategories. Is it relevant to store Categories for goods and services in *one* table or i shoud split it?

Comment: Do products and services you're modelling share the same categories? If so, one table If not, two tables.

Comment: @Schwern yeah, the categories differ. I will use separate tables. thx!

Answer (score 0):

Don't make a single table just because both things are called "categories". If products and services share the same categories, use one table. If products and services do not share the same categories, make one for each.

For example, product categories might be "cars", "toys", "muffin tins", "smoke shifters", "sky hooks". Service categories might be "accounting", "balloon twisting", "scuba instruction", "beef eater".

If products and services have different categories, one table risks putting a product into a service category or a service into a product category. If they're separate tables this is impossible.